# Twitter streaming api 140dev error

Tags: twitter, php

I am using [140dev Twitter Database Server (PHP)](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/) and I am continually getting this error in get_tweet.php.  the error I'm getting from the php-error.log file in the Windows/Temp/ directory

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$created_at in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\140dev\db\get_tweets.php on line 58
```

line 58 in get_tweets.php is:

```
$dateStamp = $this->oDB->telldate($tweet_object->created_at);
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  There are tons of other instances where `$tweet_object->created_at` is being used, but I don't get error messages in the php-errors.log file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found out that the code I've inherited was not handling all the other messages that occur in the streaming api.

to fix the logged `Notice` I set an if check before the json processing code:

```
if(isset($tweet_object->created_at)){
    //Do stuff
}
```

This resolved the `Notice` messages.  It's annoying that I didn't think of a Null check earlier.

*Note:  I did try using the `property_exists()` method in the if statement, but that still displayed the `Notice` message.  Just in case anybody was interested.